# 'tools.jar' is not in IDEA classpath

Tags: java, ide, jdk

I am a new user of Linux, it has been recommended to me by my friend.

He told me to install software called IntelliJ Idea IDE.

Well I have been following the tutorial. But now when I try to open "idea.sh", an error message pops-up:

```
'tools.jar' is not in IDEA classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

Please remember that I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm planning for a nice long stay once I get myself into it :)

Also I do not know if I am running a correct Java6 JDK.
When I do `java -version`, this is what I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre10-0ubuntu5)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Thank You for reading this and I hope I will get a nice response.

Comment: i solved same problem with this answer, maybe help 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17827697/3057033

Answer (score 62):

Be sure you have a JDK installed on your system.

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

If that does not solve your problem, you must tell your system to use that JDK instead of the current JRE. To do so, you choose which JDK/JRE you use by default on your system by executing the following command in terminal.

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

*This command will give you a list of alternative java options, which you will then be able select a JDK instead of JRE.*

Comment: this helped a lot but now I'm getting: tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

Comment: @advocate I saw your comment on SO; you issue has been resolved by reinstalling JDK, correct?

Comment: yup! just sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk

Comment: I had to set the JAVA_HOME path in ~/.bashrc before this worked.

Comment: Could you tell me how can i do this, "set the JAVA_HOME .... "

Comment: @NiteshVerma add `export JAVA_HOME=<some value>` to the file and then open a new Terminal window or type `source ~/.bashrc` to see the effects

Comment: Awesome worked like a charm

Answer (score 15):

On my Linux Mint environment I've encountered the same problem. I tried to install Oracle JDK8 using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

but the problem remained because installer didn't change environment variables.
Then I tried the following

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

and it solved the problem

Comment: Perfect solution for me and also allowed Java 8 use

Comment: this worked for me (elementary OS x64 Freya) thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this command

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

and run idea.sh again.

Mind you, this only works inside the terminal where you run the command. You will have to set the variable inside .bashrc file. This will enable it on every terminal you open.

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663658/what-is-the-correct-target-for-the-java-home-envrionment-variable-for-a-linux-op)

Comment: i tried this but still got the same error

Comment: Thank you! I know this isn't everyone's problem, but none of the other answers actually say what I should set `JAVA_HOME` to!

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

You need JDK.

Answer (score 5):

The answers above are correct but I have one thing to add. Actually the environment variables for Shell Session and Desktop GUI Session are different ([check this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/275965/how-to-list-all-variables-names-and-their-current-values/356973#356973)). If the error happens when you launch IntelliJ with Desktop Entry(the Launcher), you might don't have JAVA_HOME in your GUI Environment.

So the easiest solution is to add JAVA_HOME in the Exec line of the desktop entry like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition
Icon=/home/zhu/Applications/IntelliJ/bin/idea.png
Exec=env JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64 "/path/to/idea.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea-ce
```

Comment: Perfect solution for my issue. Adding the env argument in the Exec did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem with these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

and

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Comment: Where do you place the last command `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` you mention?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of exporting the JAVA_HOME variable doesn't work for me in Ubuntu. I solved it adding the bin directory to the PATH variable.

I downloaded the JDK from the Oracle website, and I placed it in this directory: `/home/alejandro/software/JAVA-descarga/jdk1.8.0_25`

Then you have to add that route to the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/home/alejandro/software/JAVA-descarga/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Then run the idea.sh file in the same terminal and it will start well.

Answer (score 0):

edit the file `android-studio/bin/studio.sh`

like the mark content(`JAVA_HOME` line)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Android Studio startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    JAVA_HOME=your_path/jdk1.8.0_31

message()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though on UI popup message it says

```
'tools.jar' is not in IDEA classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

on command line it shows

```
ERROR: cannot start IntelliJ IDEA.
No JDK found to run IDEA. Please validate either IDEA_JDK or JDK_HOME points to valid JDK installation
```

and this was exactly the issue for me. Setting `JAVA_HOME` did not work but had to set `JDK_HOME` to make it work.