# "Cannot locate suitable jar utility" while trying to install Oracle Java JDK

Tags: software-installation, java

I have installed jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz according to this:

[How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

But when I try to install `java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh` using the command `sudo sh java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh` from inside the /home//Downloads/ directory I get the message

> Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
>   Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
>   and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME

Note: Even though I get the mesage "Could not locate a suitable jar utility.
Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system
and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME" commands "java", "javac" are working from any location.

Comment: Just out of interest, Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If it is 11.10 or 12.04, then openjdk-7-jdk is in the repository.

Comment: @Chris Woollard-Yes Chris openjdk-7 is in the repository But I wanted to use Sun JDK7 with java_ee and also to explore how to do a manual installation, can you figure out what's going on I am using 11.10-Varuna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the same that for other programs (java, javac, javaws etc.) You just need to create an update alternative for the "jar" program like this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/jar" "jar" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/jar" 1
```

Note: remember to replace the "jdk1.7.0" path by the real name of your target jdk installation path if it is different.

Answer (score 1):

- Download the .tar.gz package from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html).
- Unzip it to a location ( say ~/java/ )
- run

  ```
   update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java"
  ```

  ( Assuming that you have update-alternatives installed already. You should, if you you openjdk installed.)

Those steps should make java available globally.

Comment: @Shggylnjun-I have installed Java according to this How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7? and is already globally available<quote>Note: Even though I get the message "Could not locate a suitable jar utility. Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME" commands "java", "javac" are working from any location</quote> The question is even though Java is globaly available why is JavaEE installation asking for a jar utility

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122133/tools-jar-is-not-in-idea-classpath/124644#124644

Take a look at that post. It should solve your JAVA_HOME problems.

But I wonder what you are trying to do that creates this error.
Considering how java development outside IDE is almost unimaginable, I say configure JDK inside the IDE, you can avoid a bunch of other issues.

Comment: When are people going to learn that JAVA_HOME has nothing to do with being able to run Java other than being a variable which clients can use to see where Java is? A simple symbolic link of all the bin contents to the /usr/bin will get Java up on most Unixes I've tried....

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty solution:

At the command prompt type:

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper fastjar
```

Now, when you run **./java_ee_sdk-6u4-unix.sh** again, it should install without a hitch.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Author: Yucca Nel http://thejarbar.org
#Will restart system
#Modify these variables as needed...
tempWork=/tmp/work
locBin=/usr/local/bin
javaUsrLib=/usr/lib/jvm

sudo mkdir -p $javaUsrLib
mkdir -p $tempWork
cd $tempWork

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2Fdownloads%2Fjdk-7u3-download-1501626.html;" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u3-b04/jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz

#Extract the download
tar -zxvf $tempWork/*

#Move it to where it can be found...

sudo mv -f $tempWork/jdk1* $javaUsrLib/

sudo ln -f -s $javaUsrLib/jdk1*/bin/* /usr/bin/
sudo rm -rf $tempWork
#Update this line to reflect newer versions of JDK...
export JAVA_HOME="$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_03"

if ! grep "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_03" /etc/environment
then
    echo "JAVA_HOME=$javaUsrLib/jdk1.7.0_03"| sudo tee -a /etc/environment
fi


exit 0
```

Comment: @thejartender-Can you please explain this I am not able to grasp what this does?